# C++: Alternative to using cast for GetProcAddress() with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, casting, pointer-arithmetic

I have a specific question about the use of GetProcAddress().
My IDE grumbles at the usual way that the cast is not ideal.
So alternatively I wrote it with pointer arithmetic.

Now my question is if this is a bad idea?
It works that way anyway.

```
HMODULE Lib = LoadLibrary(L"...");
```

**The common practice**

```
ILibBase* (*p)() = reinterpret_cast<ILibBase* (*)()>(GetProcAddress(Lib, "dllName"));
```

**Pointer arithmetic**

```
ILibBase* base = nullptr;
base += GetProcAddress(Lib, "dllName")() / 8ull;
```

Comment: Clever idea but possibly UB.  I would replace `8ull` with `sizeof (void *)` (or perhaps `sizeof (ILibBase*)`)

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on `nullptr` is outright forbidden (unless you are adding `0`).  Don't do that.  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.add#5

Comment: Nanny IDE, really.  The WIN32 API is full of casts.  Which IDE is it?

Comment: @PaulSanders JetBrains Rider :)

Comment: *The common practice* -- More likely, the pointer is aliased, so that the code that uses `GetProcAddress` doesn't look that ugly.  `MyPointerFn fn = reinterpret_cast<MyPointerFn>(GetProcAddress(Lib, "dllName"));` and `MyPointerFn` is the pointer type, aliased by using `typedef` or `using`.  Where you came up with the "Pointer Arithmetic" version, I have never seen anything like that, and doubt it will work consistently (as mentioned previously).

Comment: Even if it was guaranteed to work, the pointer arithmetic version is unusual enough that I'c consider it a poor idea. Better to just learn how to stop your IDE from arguing over the correct code (and then probably write a template so most of the code just does something like `MyFuncType foo = GetFuncAddress<MyFuncType>("name");`, and you only have one cast in one place.

Comment: The `GetProcAddress` is a `C` function that returns a generic pointer.  There is no real safe way to use it and ensure at compile time the function you are getting the address of matches the function pointer.  The safest way is to use `reinterpret_cast<>` and trust that you wrote the correct cast.  That's just the nature of utilizing `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Well no, the safest way is to use a header file created by the DLL developer.  You can do things like `decltype(&APIWhatever) dyn_APIWhatever = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&APIWhatever)>(GetProcAddress(hdll, "APIWhatever");` leveraging the header intended for import library, instead for dynamic loading.  Then you aren't on the hook for recreating the proper function signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad idea since (a) pointer size isn't always 8 and (b) actually pointer arithmetic with functions can be silly. (on older systems)

I suggest

```
typedef ILibBase* (*pointer_type)();
void *func_ptr = GetProcAddress(...); // cast of function to void *
pointer_type func = reinterpret_cast<pointer_type>(func_ptr); // void * to func
```

Comment: `using pointer_type = ILibBase* (*)();`